# In ios 7 how to increase the size of UINavigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

Used storyboard to create navigation bar. and now in ios 7 i have a challenge to increase the height of navigation bar.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];

[navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 1024, 200)];
```

Comment: are you trying to use stranded uinavigationbar are customizing it???

Comment: standard ... by using the above code, when the view loads it is showing navigation bar with given frame .... immediately changing to default sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the height of the navigation bar. It's fixed at 44 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:YourFloatSize];
CGSize titleSize = [title sizeWithFont:font];
UILabel *titleLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, titleSize.width, titleSize.height)];
titleLable.text = title;
titleLable.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLable.textColor = [UIColor anyColorYouWant];

titleLable.font = font;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLable;
```

Comment: > iOS6 .. NSTextAlignmentCenter

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNavBar)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize navSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,200);
    return navSize;
}
```